# ios 5.0 login to twitter in ios simulator issues

Tags: ios, twitter, ios-simulator

Hi I want to login in twitter account using ios simulator.

But when I try to login in simulator settings I get next message:

[image]

I enter the correct password and user name. Also I have used other account, but I still get this error.

I can not understand what the problem, but I'm sure that is not in my password and user name.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you already tried entering your credentials using the on-screenkeyboard?

Comment: thanks for response, yes I try it, but still have this problem.

Comment: You've tried resetting the simulator using `iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...`?

Comment: yes, of course I have reset my simulator, but this not help me. do you have this problem?

Comment: Nope.. But I've already heard of people having this issue on the device itself. It helped for them to restore iOS. But I don't know how to do anything like that on the simulator besides resetting it

Comment: There's one more thing I know you could try: syncing the time of your computer with Apple servers and try again..

Comment: now I try to use this on mac book and everything work good. maybe this problem on pc only (i mean on virtual machines). thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem related (in my case) with a virtual machine that I have used instead my MAC.
On MAC computer everything work good. I had tested my project on virtual MAC and on real MAC and on real MAC it work. Maybe this is related with an error when iOS SDK install on my virtual MAC and simulator have been installed incorrect (but I'm not sure).

Comment: While your answer might have worked for you, many others are still experiencing this issue, as discussed on https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4850

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in iOS Simulator 5.0.
Changed Simulator version to 6.1 and now it works as it's supposed to.

Comment: I have the same issue here, only with iOS simulator 5.x, and it is working on iOS simulator 6.1 ..